# Bash: Every command errors out to "command not found"

Tags: bash, mamp

So, I made a mistake tonight while trying to configure my MAMP installation, I edited the:

`~/.bash_profile`

afterwards I ran:

`source ~/.bash_profile`

Now, any command I run errors out like:
`-bash: cmd_name_here: command not found`
I cannot get into the file to edit it back, because when I try:

`vi ~/.bash_profile`

I will just get a "command not found" error. So how can I fix this issue?

The edit I made was to $PATH.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access `vi` directly by:

```
/usr/bin/vi
```

What happened is that you screwed up your $PATH, so bash doesn't know where any of your commands are.

Comment: Perfect, that much worked, however how would I then source it? I tried using `/usr/bin/source`, but that did not work.

Comment: Try opening up a new shell.  It should source automatically.  Also, `source` should be a built-in bash command, so you should be able to use it.

Comment: `source` is a built-in shell command (if you think about it, it has to be). Just `source ~/.bash_profile` or `. ~/.bash_profile`. Note that this might not give you the same environment you'd get in a new shell.

Answer (score 0):

Type:

```
/usr/bin/vi /home/USERNAME/.bash_profile
```

This avoids problems with `$PATH` or `$HOME` being not set.